# Scraping data presented on an overlay / new window

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am completely new to web scraping and would like to scrape reviews and property replies from: https://www.hostelworld.com/hosteldetails.php/HI-NYC-Hostel/New-York/1850#reviews

However, the HTML I obtain seems to be for the hostel page rather than the overlay page with the reviews, and I was wondering how to obtain and scrape from the reviews panel instead.

I can scrape user reviews using the snippet below,

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.hostelworld.com/hosteldetails.php/HI-NYC-Hostel/New-York/1850#reviews'

response = requests.get(url)
SoupPage = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
reviews = SoupPage.find_all(class_="review-info")

for rev in reviews:
    text = rev.find(class_="notes")
```

but it appears to be from a different source to the reviews panel since I do not see any classes or text corresponding to the property replies. Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this require login as I see a message about session expired at the bottom and I cannot view all reviews - only a small number?

Comment: @QHarr I don't believe so, I did not log in

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by the review panel and hostel page

Comment: @Fozoro The reviews load on an overlay (or slideout panel) on top of the hostel page instead of a new page. By hostel page I mean the page that includes photos and descriptions of the hostel along with its amenities. Does that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to **scrape** the whole review panel (all of the pages) I would recommend using the following link:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd

numb_of_pages = 10 #enter the number of pages you want to scrape
headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:67.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/67.0"}
df = pd.DataFrame()

for nmb in range(1,10):
    url = f"https://www.hostelworld.com/properties/1850/reviews?sort=newest&page={nmb}&monthCount=36"
    data_raw = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()
    df = df.append(data_raw["reviews"])

    print(f"page: {nmb} out of {numb_of_pages}")
```

Alternatively, if you only want a few pages worth of comments you can use the code below:

```py
import requests
import pandas

numb_of_pages = 10 #enter the number of pages you want to __scrape__ 

headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:67.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/67.0"}
df = pd.DataFrame()

for nmb in range(1,numb_of_pages):
    url = f"https://www.hostelworld.com/properties/1850/reviews?sort=newest&page={nmb}&monthCount=36"
    data_raw = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()
    df = df.append(data_raw["reviews"])
    
    print(f"page: {nmb} out of {numb_of_pages}")
    
print(df)
```

*(PS: the reviews are received in the form of a JSON string so you don't need BeautifulSoup)*

I hope this helps

Comment: That was really helpful, thank you so much :) Would you perchance know whether its possible to feed the json directly into pandas?

Comment: @BenJHC I'm glad it helped, I've just updated my code so it will store everything in a pandas DataFrame